# Working of Nested IF-Else Without the Braces

Tags: c, if-statement, conditional-statements

Can someone please explain me the working of Nested If-Else Statements written **WITHOUT** the Curly Braces.
I want to understand why Below Programme isn't giving me any output.
I've checked for all the 4 possibilities.
(Outer-If, Inner-If)::(True, True),(True, False),(False, True),(False, False).
I'm editing with CodeBlocks,using gcc compiler on Windows.

```
int main() 
{
  int n=0,m=0;
  if ( n > 0 )
       if ( m > 0 ) 
         printf("Inner-If Condition satisfied.");
  else 
     printf("Inner-If condition not satisfied. ");
  return 0;
}
```

Thank You.

Comment: Without braces, it is unknown to which `if` the `else` belongs. Indentation isn't considered by the c compiler.

Comment: `n = 0` is an **assignment** and always evaluates `false`. so with **exactly** this code, you should never see **any** output.

Comment: You are assigning  `n` an `m` the value of `0`, which is equal to false in the `if` statement.

Comment: You should probably use braces in a case like this, where it may not be clear to the reader of your code what the intention is.

Comment: @WeatherVane it belongs to the inner one

Comment: @FelixPalmen that might be the default, but it still isn't known what was intended. The indentation has just been edited.

Comment: @WeatherVane that's the rule of the language. I'm not talking about some intention we can't know :)

Comment: @FelixPalmen you missed my point. The assumption made by the compiler may not be the one the programmer intended. That can only be known by using braces.

Comment: Yeah, The problem was created by **Assignment** operator. My amateur brain was thinking of it as a condition. Actually, this is a Try-Yourself question in some book.  Thank you guys. Got it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They work *as-if* there was a curly brace around the following *statement*. In your case then:

```
if ( n = 0 ){ // ToDo - did you mean `==`, `n = 0` is `0`.
    if ( m = 0 ){ // ToDo - ditto.
        printf("True");
    } else {
        printf("False");
    }
}
```

In your case I think the bewilderment stems from your using `=` rather than `==`.

Answer (score 3):

The if-else ambiguity is solved by *defining* that an ambiguous else belongs to the nearest if.

The parser will see an ambiguity, however, the parser has ben adapted to solve the ambiguity as described above (e.g. yacc).

Note: the reason your program does not give any output is because `n=0` (an assignment) results in n being zero and so the test becomes false, so the branch is not taken and the return is executed.

Comment: Upped. That's a nice way of putting it. Feel free though to mention the `=`, `==` issue here.

Answer (score 2):

`n = 0` is an **assignment** in C. It assigns `n` the value `0`. Assignments also evaluate to the value that is assigned, so here, to `0`, which is in a boolean context `false` -- so your outer `if` is always false.

To **compare** two values, use `==` instead, which evaluates to `1` (`true`) on equality, `0` (`false`) on inequality. *)

Your assumption about `if` and `else` was correct, the reason you don't see output is just your wrong attempt at comparing values.

A good compiler will warn you of such typos. E.g. with `gcc`, enable a reasonable set of warnings with `-std=c11 -Wall -Wextra`.

---

*) as a side note, in a boolean context, a zero value is `false` and *any other value* is `true`, so you could also write the code like this (`!` is logical `not`, inverting true and false):

```
if (!n)
    if (!m)
        // ...
```

Whether this is good style depends on who you ask. I personally like to write it this way if `0` semantically represents the *lack of a value*, or if the variable is already meant as a boolean value. Then "if not n" sounds kind of natural.

Answer (score 1):

Use == inside if Statement. such as below mentioned code will work.

```
if ( n == 0 )
   if ( m == 0 )
       printf("True");
   else printf("False");
```

Comment: @BcK which has different semantics -- it would print something if `n != 0`.

Comment: @FelixPalmen My mistake apologies, `printf((n == 0) ? (m == 0 ? "True" : "False") : "");` this is the correct version but I guess, it's less readable.