# What will be the output of this code as this code is giving me a blank output and how come this can be true?

Tags: c, if-statement

Since here in my code `a` and `b` are not equal to `0`, therefore the answer must be `Bye`. But the output I am receiving is nothing. Please help!

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
    int a = 1, b = 1;
    if (a == 0)
        if (b == 0) {
            printf("HI");
        } else {
            printf("Bye");
        }
}
```

Comment: Isn't the indentation making things much clearer? Can you see your mistake now?

Comment: In this case, `&&` might help you out.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I'm not sure that was a good edit to make. You answered the question by changing the question. It would have been better to leave the question as is, and show the reformatted code in an answer.

Comment: Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_else#C

Comment: Thanks i got my explanation, Can you help me with this:

#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
int a,b=0;
if (a=b=1){
printf("hello");}
else{
printf("world");
}
return 0;
}

In my book this program is giving me "hello" as an answer. how come i am getting this answer ?

Comment: Check the [answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50099261). Note that the question was modified after the answers were posted, so be sure to read the original question in the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50099261/revisions).

Answer (score 0):

> Since here in my code a and b are not equal to 0, therefore the answer must be Bye

That would be true if the correct permutation to reach the code path containing the `printf("Bye");` line were `(a != 0) && (b != 0)`.  Your present code contains `if(a == 0) if(b == 0)`. To reach the code path containing the line `printf("Bye")`, you need for both `a` and `b` to equal zero with this code.

Solution: replace your `if` statement mess with a single `if` statement containing the correct condition.

Answer (score 0):

Because

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
    int a = 1, b = 1;
    if (a == 0)
        if (b == 0) {
            printf("HI");
        } else {
            printf("Bye");
        }
}
```

is exactly the same as

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
    int a = 1, b = 1;
    if (a == 0) {
        if (b == 0) {
            printf("HI");
        } else {
            printf("Bye");
        }
    }
}
```

Note the added set of braces for the `if (a == 0)` if-statement, and how `printf("Bye");` is enclosed within those braces.

So `printf("Bye");` won't be called unless `a` is zero and `b` is non-zero.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not print anything because the first test evaluates to false, therefore the rest of the code is skipped.

Note that there are some issues with your programming style:

- omitting the return type is no longer condoned by the C Standard, since version C99. Defining `main` as posted in your question used to work in c89 and before but only compiles with lenient compiler settings today (which sadly happens to be the default still today).
- although there is a single statement commanded by the first `if` statement, you should use braces as this statement is non trivial and extends over multiple lines.
- it is advisable to `return 0;` explicitly from `main` instead of omitting the `return` statement. C99 makes this optional but not everything that is optional should be omitted (such as proper spacing :).
- For better portability to some legacy systems, it is better to always end the output output a trailing newline.

Here is an improved version with a modified test that does print out `Bye`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a = 1, b = 1;
    if (a == 0 || b == 0) {
        printf("HI\n");
    } else {
        printf("Bye\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```